# how do I connect my twillio acct to infusionsoft

Tags: infusionsoft

I currently have Twillio sending new contact info to a campaign in Infusionsoft. 
I have changed the campaign in Infusionsoft and need to put the correct info into Twillio for the correct campaign. 
basically where twillio should send the new contact information to for follow up.

how do I change it to the correct campaign?

Comment: Welcome to SO. **We are here to help you troubleshoot or help you in the codes you provide.** Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and read the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) on how to post questions.

Comment: This may be better suited for the Infusionsoft Community Forum (http://community.infusionsoft.com/).